# How do I trigger a get request for error page here?

Tags: node.js, express

My app works as follows:
for--> `/anyOtherRoute --->error page`

But I want the following operation: for--> `/speak/goat(which is not in my database/objects) -->error page`

```
var animals={
  pig: "Oink",
  cow: "Moo",
  dog: "Woof"
};
app.get("/speak/:animal",function(req,res){
//HERE IT WILL CHECK IF THE ANIMAL IS AN OBJECT
//if not get request to the error page should be sent
    var animal=req.params.animal;
    var sound=animals[animal];
    res.send("The "+animal+" says "+sound);
});
```

I tried sending the get request inside the get request of the /speak/:animal like
/speak/anything other than :animal from objects but it didn't work.

Error page refers to:

```
app.get("*",function(req,res){
   res.send("Sorry ERROR 404"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to recognize is that an error page is no different than any other page. Knowing this, you can send back the error response from within your example:

```
var animals = {
  pig: "Oink",
  cow: "Moo",
  dog: "Woof",
  human: "Hello"
};

app.get("/speak/:animal", function(req, res) {
  var animal = req.params.animal;
  var sound = animals[animal];
  if (!sound) { // Check if sound got set to a truthy value
    res.status(404).send("Sorry ERROR 404"); // Note call to `status` to send actual 404
    return; // Stop function execution without trying to send sound
  }

  // We will only get here if we didn't `return` earlier
  res.send("The "+animal+" says "+sound);
});

app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry ERROR 404");
});
```

Now we don't want to be repeating that error message in multiple places. What if we add a bunch more similar routes and then decide we want to change what the error page looks like? We'll have to change it many different places. To clean this up, we can add a function that sends an error response for us so that we only define the message in one spot.

```
var animals = {
  pig: "Oink",
  cow: "Moo",
  dog: "Woof",
  human: "Hello"
};

function notFound(req, res) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry ERROR 404");
}

app.get("/speak/:animal", function(req, res) {
  var animal = req.params.animal;
  var sound = animals[animal];
  if (!sound) { // Check if sound got set to a truthy value
    notFound(req, res); // send the error message
    return; // Stop function execution without trying to send sound
  }

  // We will only get here if we didn't `return` earlier
  res.send("The "+animal+" says "+sound);
});

app.get("*", notFound);

// The line above is a more concise way of writing:
// app.get("*", function(req, res) {
//   notFound(req, res);
// });
```

> Disclaimer, none of this code is tested and although I proof-read it, it could be broken.

Comment: Yes I will test it and let you know.